# How can I get a percentage in a group by line?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

```
dfCountedPositions.groupby(by='Almacen')['Estatus'].agg('sum'/'count')
```

Hi i wanna get the sum divided by the count in a group by operation, do you know how can I get this percentage?

Comment: So, you want the `mean`? Replace `.agg('sum'/'count')` with `.mean()`.

Comment: No, I wanna get the percentage given by the sum divided by the count.